# An adoubt about Java multithreading skill

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Look at the code below, here's a question about it. Why I run this program, It won't stop when it comes the end? ( run it in eclipse, it need to stop manually.) Could anyone explain why?

```
public class C1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 c1 = new C1();
        c1.send();
    }
    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 5;
    private ExecutorService theadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
    public void send() {
        this.theadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("haha");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread pool contains threads that are not marked as "daemon" threads.  A JVM exits when *all* non-daemon threads have terminated.  Your "main" thread is terminating (when `main` returns) but the thread pool threads are still alive.

If you want the program to exit, either call `System.exit(...)` or call `shutdown()` on the executor.

---

> Why are the threads in thread pool still alive?

Because the thread pool keeps them alive.  One of the things that a thread pool does is to recycle threads ... because thread creation is expensive.

> As the thread go to the last step (`System.out.println("haha");`), the thread won't stop?

Correct.

The actual threadpool thread's `run()` method will call your `run()` method.  When your `run()` returns, the thread will wait for more tasks to be submitted via other calls to `execute`.

> When all threads in thread pool come to the end, are they still alive?

Ermm ... the threads in a thread pool don't "come to the end".  When a task is done, they wait for another task to be submitted.

The threadpool threads only finally terminate if you call `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` on the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's still a little not clear. Why are the threads in thread pool still alive? As the thread go to the last step (`System.out.println("haha");`), the thread won't stop? When all threads in thread pool come to the end, are they still alive?

Comment: Thanks again. Stack overflow is a good place. I have posted this question in another forum before, but nobody can give me answer, utill I come here.